# Ideal $I\cap \Bbb Z\ne(0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

What does this mean: $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$. Let $I\cap \Bbb Z\ne(0)$

What does it mean to take the intersection of an ideal and the integers? All elements of the ideal that are integers? We want the intersection of some ideal(prime here) with the integers to not be the trivial ideal?

---

Essentially we are taking some ideal $I\cap \Bbb Z \ne (0)$ and then we are deducing what $I$ looks like.

Comment: It means not choosing the ideal with one element 0 (the identity) Trivial ideal

Comment: Any ideal must have zero in it, that statement means you need an ideal with at least two elements

Comment: What ring is this $p$ supposed to be an ideal **of**?

Comment: @Zev It is an ideal where $p$ is a prime element of $\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: Here is a concrete example: the ideal generated by $2$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ consists of all the polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ with even coefficients. If we call this ideal $I$, then $I \cap \Bbb Z = 2\Bbb Z$, the even integers (we can regard the integers as a subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$ (but not an *ideal*) by considering them to be the "constant polynomials" (ones with no $x$ power terms)).

Comment: Thanks @David, you are very helpful

Answer (score 3):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ can be considered as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (the constant polynomials). Of course any ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus we can form their intersection, and in fact it will be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a roundabout way of saying that $p$ must be a nonzero integer.

If $p=0$ then of course $(p)\cap\mathbb Z=\{0\}\cap\mathbb Z=\{0\}=(0)$.

And if $p\notin\mathbb Z$, then $p$ has positive degree, and thus *every* nonzero multiple of $p$ has positive degree too. So the intersection of the principal ideal $(p)$ with $\mathbb Z$ contains only $0$.

Comment: Hmm I screwed up somewhat in my interpretation of the text. We have $I\cap \Bbb Z\ne (0)$ how does this alter the answer?

Comment: @ContinuityOfFailure: Then it just means that $I$ contains at least one nonzero integer. In particular, the integers in $I$ form an ideal of $\mathbb Z$, so $I\cap\mathbb Z$ will be either all of $\mathbb Z$ (in which case $I=\mathbb Z[X]$) or $I\cap\mathbb Z$ consists of all multiples of some prime integer $p$.

Comment: Thank you. I will see where I can get with that